# Do QVector items share the same cache-line?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, caching

Let's say I have a QVector storing this elements:
{3, 4, 1, 5, 6}. So if I read each element from different threads, will this cause false-sharing? (by 'read' I mean something like: `int i = vector[0]; //no change involved`)

And with the same concept of 'read', Is a single element of the vector considered a shared-resource when 'reading' it from different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes multiple elements will be available per cache line as `QVector` stores it's elements contiguously in memory (as does `std::vector`).

So false sharing can occur, but on modern processors it will only cause performance degradation if the cache line is modified - which it isn't in your example.

> Is a single element of the vector considered a shared-resource when
>   'reading' it from different threads?

It depends what you mean by a 'shared-resource'. If you mean a cache line marked as shared, then yes but only because the cache line *contains* the element, there's nothing special about the element itself.

If you're actually referring to Qt's implicit sharing mechanism (which `QVector` uses), then no a single element is not considered a shared resource as the reference counting occurs at the container level.

Comment: by 'shared-resource' I mean that if reading the element at the same time would cause a corruption.

Comment: @Michael reading data from multiple threads will never cause corruption. It's the synchronisation of changes between threads that causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

QVector and all the source of Qt is available for examination.

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qvector.cpp

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qvector_msvc.cpp

The official documentation says:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#details

> `QVector<T>` is one of Qt's generic container classes. It stores its
>   items in adjacent memory locations and provides fast index-based
>   access.

And there is a lot more description in there about using the `[]` operator v. using `at(int index)` v. using `data()` to access the elements of the array.

Qt Thread safety is spelled out clearly here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html

And others.